# ERROR: "/app/etc/" must exist for proper tool work magento 1.9

Tags: php, cmd, sh, patch, magento-1.9

I am trying to install the newly release security patch for magento 1.9. I am working on window system.

and I am getting the following error.

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\magento>sh PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh
ERROR: "/app/etc/" must exist for proper tool work.
```

I am running command by CMD and `SH` is working fine too

[image]

I tried with Git too. but getting same error

[image]

Not working on Linux too

[image]

can anyone tell me what is the exact issue and how it could be fixed.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Able to make it works on windows machine as well for PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh.

Problem was: CURRENT_DIR=`$PWD_BIN`/ (line 60) and the value of $PWD_BIN is defined in same file PWD_BIN=`which pwd` (line 35) as which doesn't wok on windows so we will need to replace this value.

1. Open bash
2. Your current directory should be the root of magento.
3. Run command 'pwd'
4. It will give the out path of your current directory: [Check screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/UoUwYHEDaO)
5. Copy this path and edit file, on line 67 replace:

   CURRENT_DIR=`$PWD_BIN`/ to CURRENT_DIR=`/d/xampp/htdocs/magento/`

Run patch with same commnd `sh PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh`

Note: Make sure you replace '/d/xampp/htdocs/magento/' with your directory root.

and it will work like a charm!!

Comment: @ ernitinjain : I am using cygwin to run for my wamp localhost, after i entered pwd return : /cygdrive  before of my root folder path, and also not wokring. Patch on my root folder.

Comment: How can i run by cygwin

Comment: i have changed CURRENT_DIR=   and  PATCH_BIN=

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of the forward slash at the end of line 67 seems to work better for me.

Before: `CURRENT_DIR='$PWD_BIN'/`

After: `CURRENT_DIR='$PWD_BIN'`

Answer (score 1):

In SSH, you can change the directory by entering the command, `cd /path/to/magento/location/` and then you'll be able to run the bash command to install the patch.  If you're not aware of the path, you can run the command, `pwd` which tells you your current directory.  If you're not in the right location, it's looking for **app/etc** in the wrong location (likely your root folder).  So try changing your current directory to the Magento directory and then the error should go away.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and previous answers didn't work for my situation.  The way I was able to fix the issue was to change the directory and then run the bash in SSH.

1. Run the command, `pwd`. *This will give you your current path.*
2. Change the directory to your Magento directory by running the command, `cd /path/to/your/magento/directory/`.  *This should be the path from your current location to the Magento destination.*
3. Now run the bash patch update... `bash PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh`. *Now that you're in the right location, the patch update should run smooth!*

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you are in your root directory for example and not in your Magento root. Go to your Magento folder and run you command again.

This error happens if the folder is not found or don't have enough permissions.

Use the git bash under windows that should work. With a normal CMD it's not working because there are some difference in the path and the normal CMD can't find that path from your patch file.

Comment: I am in my magento folder

Comment: Then you installation is not correct? Do you have that folder? With enough permissions?

Comment: I am working on window system and able to install extension by magento connect.

Comment: Do you use the git bash?

Comment: not working.
I am using 
sh PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh

with git bash

Answer (score 0):

I have tried above change. But, I need to do some change in that to make it working
I changed it CURRENT_DIR=$PWD_BIN to CURRENT_DIR="/D/wamp/www/magento/"
It was not working without " (quotes)

Hope this will help you.