# How to apply Magento security patches in xampp for windows

Tags: magento, xampp, patch

That must not be so difficult to do, I installed Magento CE 1.9 on xampp for windows. it works well.
I need to apply security patches that come only as .sh files, no other format is available.
I have the file, how can I apply it gives that I don't find a way to execute the .sh files under this environment?
thanks all

Comment: Cygwin, Gnu Unix utilities for Windows, read the patch files and manually apply, install Virtualbox and load a Linux VM. The first two attempt to create a Linux shell environment, the third is what you're reduced to if you can't get the first two to work and the fourth just allows you to natively develop so you don't have to jump through those annoying hoops like case insensitivity on final upload to live server. Magento is a *nix native application and development goes a lot easier under Linux or Macintosh.

Comment: Ok sir, it seams that cygwin will work, but sorry for silly questions, I dont know how to apply that after i installed cygwin, it seams so confusing process for a simple update task , isnt it? how can I update magento with the simplest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you use git bash instead. Just go at the Magento Root and run {sh Patch_file.sh}.

Answer (score 4):

1) My windows has sh.exe available and can run .sh files - just type it into the command line, git bash works fine too. 
UPDATE: my sh.exe was likely installed along with git. It is relatively easy to [install](http://git-scm.com/downloads) though.

2) On windows machines you may need to edit the PATCH-... file. Find the ``` CURRENT_DIR=``$PWD_BIN``/ ``` line. Since you will be running it from the magento root directory anyway this can be left blank. Go ahead and remove everything after the equals sign. It should now read `CURRENT_DIR=`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765450/3376305) for an explanation.

3)Now just move the file into your magento root directory and run it.

Comment: Having `sh.exe` on Windows is a good indicator that **Cygwin** or **git** have been installed. What version are you using that actually came with `sh.exe`? Would like to know what to upgrade to...

Comment: You may be right. I do have both git and cygwin installed. I'll edit the post accordingly,

Answer (score 3):

Try the Below Link Using Git-bash in Windows :

[Magento Patch File Installation in Windows](http://magento-patch-file-install-in-windows.blogspot.in/)

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin will help you to run the sh file.
[cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)
[How to use Cygwin](http://imsudo.com/how-to-use-linux-commands-in-windows/)

Comment: Cygwin will need an additional step. Run the Cygwin setup program (package manager) and select the `patch` utility package for installation.